# use one function for multiple IDs jquery toggle

Tags: jquery

Can we like shrink this code?

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $("#info1").toggle('slow');
});

$("#button2").click(function(){
    $("#info2").toggle('slow');
});

$("#button3").click(function(){
    $("#info3").toggle('slow');
});

$("#button4").click(function(){
    $("#info4").toggle('slow');
});

$("#button5").click(function(){
    $("#info5").toggle('slow');
});

$("#button6").click(function(){
    $("#info6").toggle('slow');
});

$("#button7").click(function(){
    $("#info7").toggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attribute start with selector to target button elements that starts with id button. and then evaluate the integer value in click handler from currently clicked elements id for making selector to target relevant info element. like this:

```
$("[id^=button]").click(function(){
  $('#info'+ this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0]).toggle('slow');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rkLeosvd/)**

Comment: Can you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32293221/toggle-not-working-with-datatable-responsive

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$("[id^='button']").click(function(){
    $("#info" + ($(this).index())).toggle('slow');
});
```

Instead of button ids Use Common Class something like `.button`

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $("#info" + ($(this).index() + 1)).toggle('slow');
});
```

```js
$("[id^='button']").click(function(){
        $("#info" + this.id.replace("button", "")).toggle('slow');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button1" class="button">button1</div>
<div id="button2" class="button">button2</div>
<div id="button3" class="button">button3</div>
<div id="button4" class="button">button4</div>
<div id="button5" class="button">button5</div>

<div id="info1" class="button">info1</div>
<div id="info2" class="button">info2</div>
<div id="info3" class="button">info3</div>
<div id="info4" class="button">info4</div>
<div id="info5" class="button">info5</div>
```

Comment: your solution will not work if elements are not siblings of each other

Comment: @MilindAnantwar - It will work in any case beacuse Id be unique I toggle with element id only

Answer (score 2):

The following code is an equivalent to yours:

```
for(i=1;i<8;i++) $("#button"+i).click(function({$("#info"+i).toggle('slow');});
```

Comment: Yes I know, I assumed he only wants to apply this for buttons 1 to 7, if so, all the other answers would be wrong if there is any other buttons!

Answer (score 2):

The other answers already cover a variety of quick fixes, but if you can modify the HTML of the page perhaps you can consider a more declarative approach:

### HTML

```
<button type='button' id='button1' aria-controls='info1'>Button 1</button>
<button type='button' id='button2' aria-controls='info2'>Button 2</button>
<button type='button' id='button3' aria-controls='info3'>Button 3</button>
<!-- rest of buttons -->
```

### jQuery

```
$('button[aria-controls]').click(function () {
    $(document.getElementById($(this).attr('aria-controls'))).toggle('slow');
});
```