# Toggle not working with DataTable responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

This is how I am coding:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("[id^=btnToggle]").click(function () {
        $('#infoToggle' + this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0]).toggle();
    });

    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
        responsive: true
    });

});
```

Here this code `$("[id^=btnToggle]")` is not working, but when I remove `$('#dataTables-example')` it is working fine.

I tried reversing their positions, I tried using separate document ready function, it did not work.

Please let me know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Not getting your issue here. Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

The dom(`#dataTables-example`) is modified when after calling the datatable event. due to which inner elements no more have previously attached events .You need to use event delegation in this case:

```
 $("body").on('click','[id^=btnToggle]',function () {
    $('#infoToggle' + this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0]).toggle();
});
```